# Erro ao salvar registro sem escolher a categoria no dropdownlist

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera estou com um problema ao clicar em salvar com alguns dados preenchidos acaba dando erro como poderia resolver.

[image: Ao clicar em salvar]

[image: Ao clicar em salvar]

Ao clicar em salvar da esse erro
Esse é o controller para criar

```
public ActionResult Create(Empresa empresa)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Empresas.Add(empresa);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

```
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(CombosHelper.PegarCidade(empresa.DepartamentoId), "CidadeId", "Nome", empresa.CidadeId);
        ViewBag.DepartamentoId = new SelectList(CombosHelper.PegarDepartamento(), "DepartamentoId", "Nome", empresa.DepartamentoId);
        return View(empresa);
    }
```

Esse e a função que pega as cidade.

public static List PegarCidade(int departamentoid)
        {
            var cidade = db.Cidades.Where(cid=>cid.DepartamentoId == departamentoid).ToList();
            cidade.Add(new Cidade
            {
                DepartamentoId = 0,
                Nome = "[ Selecione uma Cidade ]"
            });

`return cidade = cidade.OrderBy(dep => dep.Nome).ToList();
    }`

Se escolher o departamento e a cidade, ele salva normal, so quando tenta salvar sem escolher, precisaria colocar alguma mensagem que daquele jeito não pode, mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece devido ao fato de estar atribuindo ao placeholder "[ Selecione uma cidade ]" o valor "0" que nao existe na tabela relacionada.

Remova esse trecho e ao invés de criar o placeholder dessa forma

```
cidade.Add(new Cidade
            {
                DepartamentoId = 0,
                Nome = "[ Selecione uma Cidade ]"
            });
```

insira no HTML ao criar o dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.<campo>, Model.<campo>, "[ Selecione uma cidade ]")
```